# Which champions are suited to League of Legends Dominion Map (and which should be avoided)?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm not regularly playing League of Legends as a pre-made team and was wondering which champions are more suited to playing the [Dominion map](http://dominion.leagueoflegends.com/).

Obviously it depends a bit on what other champions have been selected for the team and your playing style but there is likely a number of champions which are more capable on this map than others...

Comment: [lol-dominion](http://i.imgur.com/V1Hob.png)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Riot games have put a special effort into having balanced champions for this game style as well. I don't believe there are any champions to avoid. However, the team composition changes a bit.

#### AP Carry

You will still need one, or else the other team will just build against AD and will own you as soon as they are a bit stuffed.

#### Tank / Off Tank

King in solo holding the bot lane, also very good in "tower diving" (if we can still call it so in Dominion).

#### Melee Fighters

They tend to be the heroes everyone picks as they are sort of kings on this map. They deal quite some damage and have high sustainability (so they don't need to Back often), and are often very good in 1v1 (which happens pretty often in Dominion).

#### Ranged AD Carry

More than one is too much, but not having one (to have more fighters) is a handicap. He deals crazy damage and can attack out of tower range or defend minion waves without exposing himself in front of the tower. From the games I've played or seen, having only melee champs is clearly a handicap.

#### Support

I rarely see them in Dominion and believe they are overlooked. Each time I've had one on my team, it was awesome to hold the windmill (we never had to back, support would always buff/heal us).
However, having a support requires good team play, because the champion won't do anything on its own (compared to fighters).

#### General

As XP gain is so fast in Dominion, teams are usually built with mid/late game champions. Riot tried to correct this in a previous patch by lowering the XP gain aura on the map, however, you still get to level 6 tremendously fast, so don't hesitate in taking weak early game champs (like Kassadin, useless before level 6).

Try having a hero or 2 (at least) with high mobility (Rammus, Kassadin, Nocturne, Twisted Fate, etc.) to do lane swaps and be unpredictable in your tower attacks.

#### Conclusion

All heroes are viable. It all depends on the team composition.

Good Akali, Irelia and Xin Zhao champions can however be freaking awesome with their ganking abilities and life steal.

Comment: +1 for an answer that describes general team makeup strategy rather than naming specific champions which would quickly become outdated.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few advantages in Dominion that don't equally apply to the classic game:



**Mobility**

Champions with high mobility can reach top first, or support lanes faster.

- Rammus (powerball + ghost = ftw)
- Blitzcrank
- Teemo
- Zilean
- Nunu
- Twisted Fate (at lvl 6)

**Sustain**

Champions who don't rely on base to heal can constantly exert pressure on towers.  Energy, heal, spell vamp, etc.

- Akali
- Sion
- Vlad

**Global Ults**

Useful for disrupting a capture or killing minions you can't reach.

- Gangplank
- Ezreal
- Lux

**Strong Pushers**

Great for bottom lane, they overwhelm the enemy with minions.

- Hermerdinger
- Nasus

This is by no means a complete list (as I'm not familiar with all the champions).  Also, I aimed for specific use cases.  Jax isn't anywhere on my list, but as a tanky melee dps, he's very well suited to dominion.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my favorites (although I haven't played tons of Dominion)

**Gangplank**:

- Great sustain with W (oranges)
- Team speed buff on short cooldown
- Global ult that is useful in many situations

  - Stop the enemy from capping
  - Initiate a teamfight on hotspot like Windmill
  - Finish off kills
  - Escape / defense
- Q is good for poking and sniping high movespeed enemies

**Wukong**:

- Got buffed with Shyvana patch
- Was already a good pick
- Great gap closer, good damage with Q
- Fairly tanky, can take some hits
- His ult is awesome for teamfights around pivotal capture points

**Udyr**

- Crazy sustain
- Very hard to kill while still doing great damage
- Bear sprint gives him mobility on short CD and stun
- Can also push lanes well

**Jarvan IV**

- Often overlooked, after numerous nerfs
- Can hold a tower pretty well
- Has strong ganks, landing E -> Q -> W does nice damage and R seals the deal
- Can poke with spear, push waves, and is kind of hard to kill

As you can see, I prefer tanky melee, but you obviously don't want to just roll with 5 tanky melee. Other known strong picks are Akali, Vayne, and Rammus.

I think just about anything can work in Dominion.  I've even seen a few very annoying Evelynns and Poppys.  I'm interested to try Tryndamere.

Answer (score 1):

The only "bad" champions are squishy champions who don't have escapes or defensive abilities. Even these champions can be good, IF they can be protected.

For example, currently Caitlyn and Graves are relatively safe picks for ranged AD. They have some abilities that help them evade melee DPS. Ashe can be devastating with her perma-slow, but ONLY IF she has someone protecting her from melee DPS - a Singed, for example can flip Wukong away from her. If you are defending a tower by yourself, or wandering the jungle by yourself, on a character like Ashe, you can be easily killed by any melee DPS or burst mage.

tl;dr - Any champion CAN be good on Dominion, but squishies need to have either protection from allies, strong CC, or escape moves.

Answer (score 0):

Personally from my experience. Melee fighters are a real popularity and are very good in 1v1 situations. But having at least one team member with a global ult can be very useful for disrupting enemies and stopping them from capturing towers or simply to just kill them.
Some examples are:
- Ezreal
- karthus
- ziggs
- Draven
ect. but even patheon (a good melee fighter) has sort of a global ult.
Hope this was.useful