# How do you play dominion in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the goal in playing Dominion in League of Legends and how do you play it? I understand you have to get as many points as possible. But it always subtracts points at different times. Why? How do you win? Make theirs' go down to 0?

Also, is it actually better for getting xp and ip compared to classic?

Comment: That's a really broad question. It's a Control Points game, where you need to gain and keep control of locations on the map. You play it by selecting Crystal Scar from the map list. As for XP/IP, they are supposed to be similar.

Comment: Don't know about XP, but Dominion is a bit better in the IP rewards, because you get like 5 bonus IP per game, win or loss. Since Dominion games are typically short, maybe 15-20 minutes on average, that is significant and makes Dominion the highest IP per hour mode.

Comment: Related: [IP gain](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29606/how-much-ip-do-you-get-for-winning-losing-games-in-the-various-modes-maps), [basic Dominion play](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108729/what-is-the-basic-dominion-strategy) and [good champs to use](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/which-champions-are-suited-to-league-of-legends-dominion-map-and-which-should-b?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

The point is actually *not* to get as many points. That's just your personal score. It means as much to winning as your K/D/A (nothing).

The scoreboard at the top shows the HP of both team's Nexus. It starts at 500 and to win you must drop the enemies to 0.

Under the scoreboard at the top you'll notice some dots. There are 5 total and are red, gray or blue. These represent the 5 control points on the map. Gray means uncaptured and neutral. Red is enemy controlled. Blue is Friendly controlled.

Every couple of seconds, the team that controls less points loses 1 hp from their Nexus for every less control point they have. If one team has 3 points and the other has 2, the team with 2 points will lose 1 Nexus hp per second. Let's say the losing team makes one of the opponent points neutral. Then both teams would control 2 points each and one is neutral. Neither team would lose points.

Controlling points isn't the only way to drop the enemy Nexus HP though. Kills will also drop it by 2 as long as the nexus has more than 100 hp left.

Answer (score 0):

In the game of Dominion, there are 5 towers that can be captured by either team.  Your team loses health if the opposing team controls more towers than your team.  The more towers a team controls, the faster the other team loses their health.

A game of Dominion ends when either teams life hits zero; the winning team is the team with health remaining.

---

Because of this unique gameplay, Dominion games can go very fast - sometimes less than 10 minutes.  This makes them an attractive option for getting a daily win bonus!